# I tried to export audio using RenderToFile, but when I set scheduledTime, it doesn't work

Tags: swift, audiokit

I merged two audios,one of which I set the scheduledTime. When I just play it, it works. But when I use RenderToFile to export and start to play the audio which I exported, the scheduledTime doesn't work.

```
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"music_1" ofType:@"mp3"];

AKAudioFile *file1 = [[AKAudioFile alloc]initForReading:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] error:nil];
AKAudioFile *file2 = [[AKAudioFile alloc]initForReading:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2] error:nil];

AKAudioPlayer *player1 = [[AKAudioPlayer alloc]initWithFile:file1 looping:NO lazyBuffering:YES error:nil completionHandler:nil];
AKAudioPlayer *player2 = [[AKAudioPlayer alloc]initWithFile:file2 looping:NO lazyBuffering:YES error:nil completionHandler:nil];

player2.scheduledTime = player1.duration;
AKMixer *mixer = [[AKMixer alloc]init:@[player1,player2]];
AudioKit.output = mixer;

AVAudioFormat *format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc]initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat64 sampleRate:44100 channels:2 interleaved:NO];
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:format.settings];
[settings setObject:@(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
AKAudioFile *file = [[AKAudioFile alloc]initForWriting:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/justTest.aac",MineAudioURL]] settings:settings error:nil];

[AudioKit renderToFile:file duration:player1.duration+player2.duration error:nil prerender:^{
   [player1 start];
   [player2 start];
}];
```

When I play it `player2` will play after `player1` has finished. But when I use `RenderToFile` to export and start to play the audio which I exported, both play at the same time. And this is not what I want. I want `audio2` to play when `audio1` has finished.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more precise in your question ti have a chance to get a valuable feedback. See  [ask]